# How to mark quantity to invoice on Purchase Order Line? Can I use 'Finished' field?

Tags: c#, web-services, navision, dynamics-nav

I am trying to count `Qty_to_invoice` in `Purchase_Order_Line`, but the value of this field is 0 at the very beginning, so I have to initialize it with Purchase Order Line's `Quantity` field.  Problem is when it goes back to 0.  How can I mark that all the invoices for this line are received?

I have found 'Finished' field in the Purchase_Order_Line, but I am not sure if I can use it. Can I? Can I?  I am not sure what the system will use it for later...

Or just point me to the API documentation, if there is any, please.  Something with description of all this fields would be great to read.

//ETDI:  I use Web Services(Page) to access NAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the value of this field is 0 at the very beginning, so I have to initialize it

I cant guess what exactly you are trying to do with Purchase Line, but fields like Qty. to Invoice and Qty. to Receive in most cases filled automatically when validating Quantity. Both sets equal to Quantity. Validate triggers when user enters something to field on the form or from C/AL code by calling `PurcaseLine.VALIDATE("Quantyity", number);`

> Problem is when it goes back to 0. How can I mark that all the invoices for this line are received?

When you posting an invoice posted quantity is added to the field `Qty. Invoiced` and received quantity added to field `Qty. Received`. So at any time you know how many item received and payed. *Both fields are readonly for user because only posting procedures can and must change those.*

So if you have Qty. = 10, then you post 4 of them (Qty. to Invoice = 4) and Qty. Invoiced = 0.
You'll get Qty. = 10, Qty. to Invoice = 6, Qty. Invoiced = 4.
Qty. to Invoice in this case is rest of the qty. to be invoiced.

You shouldn't use any fields if you don't know their purpose. Field 'Finished' for example is part of Production Orders functionality and not related to Qty. to Invoice at all.

To find out meaning of a field you can refer to help (press F1 while standing on a field in table). That work not for every field. Another way (if you are developer and have license) is to use Developer Tool Kit (it can be found on installation CD or [here](http://www.mibuso.com/dlinfo.asp?FileID=1107)). This utility allows to search for dependencies between Nav objects.

---

Regarding to web-services.
Do not try to use those tables directly. Its really causes a lot of troubles and inconvenience. Create new operational tables. Name them `Purchase Order Import` and `Purchase Line Import`. Create pages for them and publish as web-services. Import your data into them in whatever you like format. I mean the tables can be clones of real tables or just have few fields you need.
Put some code into `OnModify` trigger of the pages which will be called at the end of the import or publish codeunit with function that will create or update purchase orders and lines from Import-tables.
Clear Import-tables after all.

If your task is to partially post receipts based on quantity from external system, then your steps will be:

1. assume Purchase Order and Line created, Qty is 100, you need to post this qty in portions
2. import Qty to be posted via web-service to Purchase Line Import table through page
3. OnModify of the page will be triggered, put some code to that trigger to update Purchase Line's `Qty. to Invoice` **-or-** call some codeunit via web-service and update Purchase Line's `Qty. to Invoice`. Put all business logic on creating and updating purchase line here, not in your external application.
4. Now you have Qty = 100, Qty to Invoice = 5.
5. Call posting codeunit via web service. Of course don't publish posting codeunit itself. Call it through another codeunit that is published.
6. Now you have Qty = 100, Qty to Invoice = *don't really care*, Invoiced Qty = 5, and you can repeat steps 2-5 again.

You shouldn't care about Qty to Invoice is thats why: next time you import next portion of qty all you need to check is Import_Qty < (Qty - Invoiced Qty). If true you can post, otherwise you cant.

Comment: Problem is that 'Qty_invoiced' is 0 at all the times.  I think the invoice must be approved to count in this field.  So I have `Qty_to_invoice` which I use and the value is 0 at the start. I have to fill it and I have to keep counting "manually".  Field `Qty_invoiced" is read only.  I did not mentioned that I use Web Services to access NAV, maybe that is important?

Comment: How web-service is published: page or codeunit? And what exactly are you trying to do? Create order, get order, post it or...

Comment: by the way the fact that you're using web-services totally changes your initial question.

Comment: It is a page and I have no VALIDATE method there.  Sorry I did not mention that at the beginning.  I am importing invoices into the NAV system and I try to manipulate PO data to reflect incoming invoice.

Comment: Do you have access to Nav itself? I mean have you seen it, how it works?

Comment: I have my installation and demo company(CRONOS ltd.) setup.  This is my testing environment.  I have done posting invoices into the NAV, but I am trying to match PO and automate the process of rejecting invoices if there is to many items invoiced for the PO.  Anyway, I think I will just check if `Quantity` is less or equal to invoiced items quantity and maybe I will let the user take care about the rest.  I cannot see another option since PO number is not in the invoice object and I cannot change `Qty_invoiced`.

Comment: In most cases Nav just will not let you do such things like post more than it is in the order. It will throw error on field validation or on posting itself.